# How to make my view better to save Django

Tags: django, function, save, django-views

Hy guys sorry for this post but i need help with my application, i need optimize my view. I have 5 models, how i can do this?

```
def save(request):  

    # get the request.POST in content
    if request.POST:
        content = request.POST
        dicionario = {}
        # create a dict to get the values in content 
        for key,value in content.items():
            # get my fk  Course.objects
            if key == 'curso' :
                busca_curso  = Curso.objects.get(id=value)
                dicionario.update({key:busca_curso})
            else:
                dicionario.update({key:value})
        #create the new teacher
        Professor.objects.create(**dicionario)
```

my questions are?

1 - How i can do this function in a generic way? Can I pass a variable in a %s to create and 
get? like this way ?

```
foo = "Teacher" , bar = "Course" 

def save(request, bar, foo):
    if request post:
    ...
    if key == 'course' :
       get_course = (%s.objects.get=id=value) %bar
       ...
    (%s.objects.create(**dict)) %foo ???
```

i tried do this in my view but don't work =/, can somebody help me to make this work ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing this all manually you should use [ModelForms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). That way you can simply create a form that will automatically create your object upon calling `save()`.

Example:

```
class ProfessorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Professor

def save(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfessorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have more than one of these forms, you actually want formsets: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

The docs do a fantastic job of describing how to throw a form with a queryset together into a formset to edit more than one thing at a time :)